# Where can i find j2ee 1.4 sdk update 1?

Tags: java

J2EE 1.4 SDK update 1 is required for my project. Goggled a lot but couldn't find it. So it would be great if any one have a link to download J2EE SDK update 1 specifically. If you know or find a link don't forget to forward me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Archived Java releases

You can find old versions in the [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html):

> The Oracle Java Archive offers self-service download access to some of our historical Java releases.
>
> WARNING: These older versions of the JRE and JDK are provided to help developers debug issues in older systems. **They are not updated with the latest security patches and are not recommended for use in production.**